# Numpy Array Math to copy pixels instead of iterating through a For loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm pulling in a 4000 wide x 2000 high flat map of the earth (`src_filename`) and have pre-calculated the pixel relocation x, y values which are stored in a `numpy.ndarray` (`transform_array`, 2000, 2000, 2).

The relocated pixels are supposed to be copied from a `srcimg_array` to a 2000x2000 `polarimg_array` which gets saved out to an image.

I have a for loop that iterates through the `transform_array`, reads the location value in each location, and then copies pixel RGB value from the source to the polar array - ie: `transform_array` [0, 0] contains [1414, 1500] which means the source image color values at [0, 0] get copied to [1414, 1500] in the `polarimg_array`, [0, 1] value gets copied to [1413, 1500], etc.

This process takes about 30 seconds per image and I'm trying to speed that process up.

How can this be accomplished using Python? (ie: not C or Cython or the like).

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

global transform_array
transform_array = np.zeros((2000, 2000, 2), dtype='i')
# transform_array values are pre-calculated already

srcimg_array = np.array(imageio.imread(src_filename))

polarimg_array = np.zeros((outputHeight, outputWidth, 3), dtype='uint8')

for item in np.ndindex((2000, 2000)):
    XYgrid = transform_array[item[0], item[1]]
    polarimg_array[[item[1]], [outputHeight - item[0]]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

Comment: In your code you seem to be copying instead "source image color values at **[1414 -1500]** to **[column,outputHeight - row]** in the polarimg_array". Anyway, seems like you can use [Array Indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) since you already have the the indices of the pixel values that you want to extract into another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, like [sai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10733051/sai) mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818057/numpy-array-math-to-copy-pixels-instead-of-iterating-through-a-for-loop-in-pytho#comment116372334_65818057) if you want to relocate pixels from `srcimg_array` to `polarimg_array` based on `transform_array` like you explained in your question:

> I have a for loop that iterates through the transform_array, reads the location value in each location, and then copies pixel RGB value from the source to the polar array - ie: transform_array [0, 0] contains [1414, 1500] which means the source image color values at [0, 0] get copied to [1414, 1500] in the polarimg_array, [0, 1] value gets copied to [1413, 1500], etc.

Then you would use for loop like this:

```
for item in np.ndindex((2000, 2000)):
    XYgrid = transform_array[item[0], item[1]]
    polarimg_array[item[0], item[1]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

I don't understand what are you trying to do with your for loop:

```
for item in np.ndindex((2000, 2000)):
    XYgrid = transform_array[item[0], item[1]]
    polarimg_array[[item[1]], [outputHeight - item[0]]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

It seems like you are trying to do some kind of additional transformation. If that's the case then you should apply that transformation on `transform_array` so that `transform_array` contains all transformations that you need, and then relocate pixels based on `transform_array` using for loop written above (the first for loop mention in my answer).

Also, in this line:

```
polarimg_array[[item[1]], [outputHeight - item[0]]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

You have put indexes `item[1]` and `outputHeight - item[0]` inside an array (so you have `[item[1]]` and `[outputHeight - item[0]]` as indexes) which is not only unnecessary but also (for some strange reason) it significantly slows down the execution of for loop. (On my computer it was about 5 times faster when I removed unnecessary square brackets). So, this line should be like this:

```
polarimg_array[item[1], outputHeight - item[0]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

And finally back to the main problem, can copying pixels in this for loop be faster:

```
for item in np.ndindex((2000, 2000)):
    XYgrid = transform_array[item[0], item[1]]
    polarimg_array[item[0], item[1]] = srcimg_array[XYgrid[0], XYgrid[1]]
```

You can use array indexing in NumPy (also mentioned by [sai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10733051/sai) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818057/numpy-array-math-to-copy-pixels-instead-of-iterating-through-a-for-loop-in-pytho#comment116372334_65818057)). You can find detailed information and examples of array indexing in NumPy [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). In short:

> Integer array indexing allows selection of arbitrary items in the array based on their N-dimensional index. Each integer array represents a number of indexes into that dimension.

[Example](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing):

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
                  [ 3,  4,  5], 
                  [ 6,  7,  8], 
                  [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> rows = np.array([[0, 0],
                     [3, 3]], dtype=np.intp) 
>>> columns = np.array([[0, 2],
                        [0, 2]], dtype=np.intp)
>>> x[rows, columns]
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

This next line will do what we want:

```
polarimg_array = srcimg_array[transform_array[:,:,0], transform_array[:,:,1]]
```

I will explain how this works on a simple example on the image of just 6 pixels.

[image: Example image of 6 pixels]

For this image `srcimg_array` will be:

```
array([[[200,   0,   0],
        [150,   0,   0],
        [100,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0, 200],
        [  0,   0, 150],
        [  0,   0, 100]]], dtype=uint8)
```

If we want to flip image horizontally then `transform_array` would be:

```
>>> transform_array = np.array([[[j, 2 - i] for i in range(3)] for j in range(2)])
>>> transform_array
array([[[0, 2],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 0]]])
```

Variable `transform_array[:,:,0]` will contain heights of transformed positions and `transform_array[:,:,1]` will contain widths of transformed positions. (`:,:,0` means that we are selecting everything (`:`) from the first dimension, everything (`:`) from the second dimension, and element on position `0` in the third dimension.)

```
>>> transform_array[:,:,0]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])

>>> transform_array[:,:,1]
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Finaly:

```
>>> polarimg_array = srcimg_array[transform_array[:,:,0], transform_array[:,:,1]]
>>> polarimg_array
array([[[100,   0,   0],
        [150,   0,   0],
        [200,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0, 100],
        [  0,   0, 150],
        [  0,   0, 200]]], dtype=uint8)
```

For example, `polarimg_array[1, 2]` is `[  0,   0, 200]` because `transform_array[:,:,0][1, 2]` is `1` and `transform_array[:,:,1][1, 2]` is `0` so `polarimg_array[1, 2]` is equal to `srcimg_array[1, 0]`.

The resulting image is:

[image: The resulting image]

Here is full code example:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

transform_array = np.zeros((2000, 2000, 2), dtype='i')
# transform_array values are pre-calculated already

srcimg_array = np.array(imageio.imread(src_filename))

polarimg_array = srcimg_array[transform_array[:,:,0], transform_array[:,:,1]]
```

On my computer on an image of size 4000x2000, the time it takes to create `polarimg_array` is about 0.1 seconds.

**Edit** (after [cpuguru's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312/cpuguru) comments):

I looked at your [code](https://github.com/cpuguru/operationcode/blob/main/polar_pair_2.py) and managed to create the transformation that you need. (I wrote function `getTransformation` that creates `transform_array` so we can use `srcimg_array[transform_array[:,:,0], transform_array[:,:,1]]` to get `polarimg_array`.) This is full simplified code example. (I remove argument parsing, logging, multiprocessing and performance improvement with numba):

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import imageio

def getTransformation(height, outputHeight, outputWidth):
    ts_rows, ts_columns = np.indices((outputHeight, outputHeight))
    ts_rows = ts_rows - outputHeight / 2
    ts_columns = ts_columns - outputHeight / 2
    transform_src = np.zeros((outputHeight, outputHeight, 2), dtype='int')
    transform_src[:,:,0] = np.arctan2(ts_columns, ts_rows) * height / np.pi
    transform_src[:,:,1] = np.sqrt(ts_rows*ts_rows + ts_columns*ts_columns) \
                           * height / outputHeight
        
    tn_columns, tn_rows = np.indices((outputHeight, outputHeight))
    tn_rows = outputHeight - 1 - tn_rows
    transform_north = transform_src[tn_rows, tn_columns]    
    transform_north = transform_north[:,:,::-1]

    ts_columns, ts_rows = np.indices((outputHeight, outputHeight))
    ts_rows = ts_rows - outputHeight
    transform_south = transform_src[ts_rows, ts_columns]
    transform_south[:,:,1] = height - transform_south[:,:,1] - 1
    transform_south = transform_south[:,:,::-1]

    transform_array = np.zeros((outputHeight, outputWidth, 2), dtype='int')
    transform_array[:,:outputHeight,:] = transform_north
    transform_array[:,outputHeight-4:,:] = transform_south
    return transform_array
        

def EquirectangularToPolar(src_filename, transform_array):
    srcimg_array = np.array(imageio.imread(src_filename))

    polarimg_array = srcimg_array[transform_array[:,:,0], transform_array[:,:,1]]

    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(src_filename))[0]
    dst_filename = ''.join([name, '_pp.', 'jpg'])
    imageio.imsave(dst_filename, polarimg_array)
    print("Saving " + dst_filename)
    return


def main():
    starttime = time.time()
    filename = 'wind_waves_0001.jpg'

    height = 2000
    width = 4000
    outputHeight = height
    outputWidth = width - 4

    starttime = time.time()
    
    transform_array = getTransformation(height, outputHeight, outputWidth)

    EquirectangularToPolar(filename, transform_array)

    print('File conversion took {0:.2f} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Function `getTransformation` creates `transform_array` which is than used in function `EquirectangularToPolar` to apply the transformation to each image.
In the code above, I assumed that all of your images are of the same size so you can use the same `transform_array` on all of your images (or at least the same `transform_array` on images of the same size) which gives you additional performance improvement.

Explanation of how function `getTransformation` works:

- The first part creates `transform_src`. `transform_src` is an array of size `(outputHeight, outputHeight, 2)` such that `transform_src[x][y]` is equal to `findSrcXY(x, y, height, outputHeight)`. Instead of calcuating `findSrcXY` for each coordinate `(x, y)` we calculate it for all x-coordinates together, and together for all y-coordinates. NumPy is very fast when operation is applied on the whole array instead of applying that operation on each element of the array seperatly. In first line:

  ```
  ts_rows, ts_columns = np.indices((outputHeight, outputHeight))
  ```

  `ts_rows` and `ts_columns` are initiated so that `ts_rows` containes x-coordinates and `ts_columns` contains y-coordinates of all positions in array of size (outputHeight, outputHeight).

  Next two lines:

  ```
  ts_rows = ts_rows - outputHeight / 2
  ts_columns = ts_columns - outputHeight / 2
  ```

  replace this code:

  ```
  x = x - outputHeight / 2
  y = y - outputHeight / 2
  ```

  And last two lines:

  ```
  transform_src[:,:,0] = np.arctan2(ts_columns, ts_rows) * height / np.pi
  transform_src[:,:,1] = np.sqrt(ts_rows*ts_rows + ts_columns*ts_columns) * height / outputHeight
  ```

  are doing the same thing as functions `findSrcX` and `findSrcY`.
- In the second and third part of function `getTransformation`, arrays `transform_north` and `transform_south` are created. `transform_north` is the transformation needed for the left side of the resulting image, and `transform_south` is needed for the right side of the image. Array `transform_north` replaces this line:

  ```
  polarimg_array[coord_target[1], outputHeight - coord_target[0]] = srcimg_array[coord_src[1], coord_src[0]]
  ```

  Again in first line `ts_rows` and `ts_columns` are initiated:

  ```
  tn_columns, tn_rows = np.indices((outputHeight, outputHeight))
  ```

  This time `ts_rows` and `ts_columns` are reversed because `coord_target` is reversed in `polarimg_array[coord_target[1], outputHeight - coord_target[0]]` (On first index is `coord_target[1]` and on second index is `coord_target[0]`.)

  Then next line:

  ```
  tn_rows = outputHeight - 1 - tn_rows
  ```

  replaces `outputHeight - coord_target[0]` in `polarimg_array[coord_target[1], outputHeight - coord_target[0]]`. (I added `-1` so that the resulting image starts from the first column (which is indexed zero), if you look at your images (in png format) you'll see that the first column is just black, I assumed that was not desired outcome.)

  In next line:

  ```
  transform_north = transform_src[tn_rows, tn_columns]
  ```

  we get value from `transform_src` at right position.

  And in the last line:

  ```
  transform_north = transform_north[:,:,::-1]
  ```

  we reverse positons (from (x, y) to (y, x)) because `coord_src` positons in `srcimg_array[coord_src[1], coord_src[0]]` are reversed.

  Array `transform_south` is created similary to `transform_north`.
- The last part of function `getTransformation` combines `transform_north` and `transform_south` in one array `transform_array`.

Like I said, function `getTransformation` is significantly faster than the previous solution because we apply all operations on whole arrays. These are (approximate) times it took for parts of program on my pc:

- 0.8 seconds to create `transform_array` (with `getTransformation` function)
- 0.2 seconds to create `srcimg_array` (opening image)
- 0.3 seconds to create `polarimg_array` (applying transformation)
- 0.2 seconds for `imageio.imsave` function (saving resulting image)

With your code (with performance improvements) transformation took about 1 minute. You can try to improve my solution with multiprocessing and numba, but if all your images are of the same size then you create `transform_array` (call `getTransformation`) only once and call function `EquirectangularToPolar` once for each image (which takes about 0.7 seconds). Given that opening and saving image takes about 0.4 seconds, performance improvements would make sense only if you can speed up the process of opening and saving image.

Comment: Awesome answer! The 2000,2000 is me trying to simplify the question by limiting it to a static size. The code I'm trying to replace processes the top half of the map, paints the left-hand side of the image, flips the map and then paints the right-hand side of the image. 2000x2000 left, shift over 2000 & 2000x2000 right = 4000x2000

Comment: I'm batch converting 180 images in each folder, so my thought was to compute the pixel remapping & store it in transform_array and then apply the pixel remapping values to each image. That would eliminate it recalculating the transform for each image.

Comment: I will try to help you with the transformation, but I'm not sure that I understood what you are trying to do. Are you trying to transform the image like [this](https://prnt.sc/xq2g63)?

Comment: Converting this: https://www.oceanic.udel.edu/globaldataview/OmniGlobe/NRL/wind_waves/wind_waves_0001.jpg to this: https://www.oceanic.udel.edu/globaldataview/OmniGlobe/NRL/wind_waves/polarpair/wind_waves_0001.jpg so that it can be displayed on this: https://arcscience.com/globe-products-2/

Comment: The right-hand side is always minus 4 pixels (proprietary requirement for the globe) which complicates things for me. The original script which is super slow is here: https://github.com/cpuguru/operationcode/blob/main/polar_pair.py with the reimagined script using array math here: https://github.com/cpuguru/operationcode/blob/main/polar_test.py - happy to discuss offline so I don't get called out by the moderators ;?)

Comment: This v2.0 version that a co-worker helped me with is over 10x faster than the original polar_pair.py script - so this is what I'm trying to tweak going forward. If you are up to still willing to help it would be the working script going forward. https://github.com/cpuguru/operationcode/blob/main/polar_pair_2.py

Comment: Another suggestion I was given was to look into "memoization" - https://towardsdatascience.com/memoization-in-python-57c0a738179a

Comment: I edited my answer to include code for a faster solution. (I looked at your v2.0 version of code and created the transformation (`transform_array`) that you need). The whole solution (with one image) takes about a second and a half on my PC. Also, I don't think you can use memoization in this case. (Memoization is used when you calculated something multiple times, so instead of calculating each time you save it when it is first calculated and then read it from memory when you need it again. In your program, you don't calculate the same thing multiple times. )

Comment: Feedback - created a v3 using the getTransformation code. 
https://github.com/cpuguru/operationcode/blob/main/polar_pair_3.py
Timing to convert 180 images with mapped to 32 cores (-p 32) is:
polar_pair.py - 371 seconds
polar_pair_2.py - 11.34 seconds
polar_pair_3.py - 19.34 seconds